# Degree 2, 3 variable homogenous instance for Hilbert's Tenth Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, decidability

I know that Hilbert's Tenth problem is uncomputable as shown by Matiyasevich's theorem, but for a special case, is Hilbert's tenth problem decidable for degree two homogenous $3$ variable instance of the problem? In other words is $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$ has a non trivial zero $\in \mathbb{Z^3}$ decidable?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767695/is-hilberts-tenth-problem-decidable-for-degree-2)

Comment: The title is very broad for a narrow class of Diophantine equations.

Comment: Incidentally, if there is one non-trivial answer, there are infinitely many answers.

Comment: From the link posted, can I still belief that this has hope for the general  degree 2, 3 variable equations. I am asking this cause, if this still has hope, I will invest my time on this problem. Is it worth?

Comment: @roydiptajit My guess would be that degree $2$ can be even decided for every number of variables. I can barely imagine that degree $2$ is undecidable with just $3$ variables, so if this has actually not have been tried before, you can try to establish a proof. My guess is that someone did it already, but I have no reference.

Comment: Okay, I get that decision version of the problem is closed, but finding integral roots is still open is what I think..for degree two and higher. Number of variables I do not have any idea..